# Jmeter: Saving response of a sampler inside a loop controller in a array variable

Tags: arrays, loops, http, controller, jmeter

```
    --Loop_controller
       |--Http_Request_Sampler_One

    --Http_Request_Sampler_Two
```

I have a sampler (**Http_Request_Sampler_One**) with a response body *{"id": "**12345**"}*.

This sampler is in a **loop controller**, which will run *3 times for example*.

I want a **string array variable** named **Ids** to hold all the id.
in the form ***Ids = ["12345", "23421", "43546"]***

I want to use this **Ids** variable in **Http_Request_Sampler_Two** once the loop controller ends.

***Note: I'm able to extract the id from the response body using JSON-extractor, I'm more interested in knowing a way to push it in an array after each iteration ends.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of your `Http_Request_Sampler_One`
2. Put the following code into "Script" area

   ```
   if (vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx') == '0') {
       def Ids  = []
       Ids.add(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).id)
       vars.put('Ids', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(Ids).toPrettyString())
   }
   else {
       def Ids = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('Ids'))
       Ids.add(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).id)
       vars.put('Ids', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(Ids).toString())
   }
   ```
3. That's it, once your Loop Controller finishes you will get all the "ids" extracted from the `Http_Request_Sampler_One` as `${Ids}` JMeter Variable.

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Comment: It worked, But how do I get the length of this Ids variable? I tried ${Ids.length()} but it isn't working.

Comment: Have you tried to read the referenced articles? I believe they do contain all the answers. Just in case you prefer to copy and paste the code without understanding what it is doing, here is how you can get the length of the array: `${__groovy(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(vars.get('Ids')).size(),)}`. In case you want to have more insight: [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter)

Comment: The referenced article doesn't contain, how to access the nth element of this array variable, I tried using ${Ids.get(n)} and ${Ids[n]} but none worked.